# Algorithm for similarity?

Tags: algorithm, similarity

If this may seem like a duplicate, I apologize, but as the previous question seemed to have stirred some confusions, here is another go.

I have 2 base arrays:

```
float[] baseArr1 = new float[3] {0.430651724, 0.137407839, 0.177024469};
float[] baseArr2 = new float[3] {0.718210936, 0.001312795, 0.009634903};
```

And another 2 arrays for comparison:

```
float[] compArr1 = new float[3] {1, 1, 1};
float[] compArr2 = new float[3] {1, 0, 0};
```

compArr1 and compArr2 are then compared with baseArr1 and baseArr2. I know the answer that I should get but I am having difficulty coming up with an algorithm to come up with the answer. When comparing to baseArr1, the answer should be compArr1 and when comparing to baseArr2, the answer should be compArr2.

Please note that the values of both baseArrs do not necessarily have to add up to 1. Additionally, here are two more concise arrays to try and make my point clearer:

```
float[] extraArr1 = new float[3] {.5, .3, .3};
float[] extraArr2 = new float[3] {.75, 0, 0};
```

In which extraArr1 is 'closer' to compArr1 and extraArr2 is 'closer' to compArr2. I've tried the Cosine Similarity algorithm as suggested by some, but there are times in which the answer is incorrect.

The criteria is having 'more' of the value per element. For example, compArr1 has 'more' values that are closer to baseArr1 than compArr2 and compArr2 has greater 'closeness' to baseArr2 than compArr1 has to baseArr2.

Thank you!

UPDATE:

I got the answer! I'll be posting it here for future reference, I admit I had a lot of trouble and also gave confusion to other people but thanks also for trying to help me! Here is what I made:

```
float[] pbaseArrX = new float[3];
float[] pcompArrX = new float[3];

float dist1 = 0, dist2 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < baseArrX.Count; i++)
{
  pbaseArrX[i] = baseArrX[i] / (baseArrX[0] + baseArrX[1] + baseArrX[2]);
}

//Do the following for both compArr1 and compArr2;
for (int i = 0; i < compArrX.Count; i++)
{
  pcompArrX[i] = pcompArrX[i] / (pcompArrX[0] + pcompArrX[1] + pcompArr[2]);
}

//Get distance for both
for (int i = 0; i < pcompArrX.Count; i++)
{
  distX = distX + ((pcompArrX[i] - pbaseArrX[i])^2);
}

//Then just use conditional to determine which is 'closer'
```

Comment: It seems to me that baseArr1 is closer to `{1, 0, 0}` than `{1, 1, 1}`. Are you sure about the values?

Comment: As long as you only provide examples of desired input-output pairs, there are an (uncountably!) infinite number of possible algorithms. What are your criteria? It seems to have something to do with the relative magnitudes of the scalar values, but what your cutoff points are is not obvious.

Comment: @Pontus, there are only a countably infinite number of possible algorithms.

Comment: "When comparing to baseArr1, the answer should be compArr1 and when comparing to baseArr2, the answer should be compArr2." Based on what criteria?

Comment: The criteria is having 'more' of the value per element. For example, compArr1 has 'more' values that are closer to baseArr1 than compArr2 and compArr2 has greater 'closeness' to baseArr2 than compArr1 has to baseArr2.

Comment: That doesn't help one bit. All you've done was say the same thing and added quotation marks. "closeness" is not a defined notion. What you describe can still be implemented in an infinite number of ways. Imagine I ask you to help me with an algorithm that given a number, finds the "best" number greater than the input. What is the "best" number? In the same vein, there is no "closeness" without a formal definition.

Comment: @davin: my bad: I meant to say 'functions'. Although I'm starting to wonder if there actually is a deterministic process for answering the OP's question...

Comment: @Pontus Hi! Ive updated my post with the answer I came up with. Ive already tested it using excel and the following values I gave. Thanks to everyone for the help!

Comment: @user Just try using your _answer_ for comparing {-1, 0, 1} ...

Answer (score 6):

You want to find the closest - to baseArr1 - array from all compArrX arrays.

There are various distances that can be used. Most common are:

- [**Euclidean distance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)
- [**Minkowski distnce**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance)
- [**Taxi-cab or Manhattan distance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) (this is Minkowski with `p=1`)
- [**Chebysev distance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) (this is Minkowski with `p=infinity`)

and many others like:

- [**Mahalanobis_distance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) which is scale invariant. If you search for statistics and correlation, you'll find more complex algorithms that perhaps fit to your problem. See wikipedia's [**Correlation_and_dependence**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)

We can't know which one fits best your data model.

Comment: I like mahalanobis distance. You can make it work by taking comp variables to be the mean, and adding standard deviations: large standard deviations for second and third component of comp1, and tiny ones for comp2. :)

Comment: @Dysaster: Yes, I too think that a scale-invariant method might be what the OP wants (based on the second example `{.5, .3, .3}`)

Answer (score 1):

Another similarity (or dissimilarity) measure - [Earth Mover's Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance)

Comment: But that measures similarity between distributions, not points. How would you implement that measure to points?

Comment: EMD is plausible in case the OP wants a scale-invariant thing, in which case the points should be normalized to unit vectors. The wiki article mentions the possibility of extending EMD to vectors with differing sums of coordinates, but I haven't seen that formalized.